# Secure webSocket on local network for android browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, ssl, wss, ws

I am trying to run a web on my local network that connects to the server through a websocket. When I test it from the same machine that is serving the web (localhost) it works fine but when I try to access the web from my android phone with chrome I get "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". It seems that chrome refused all connections to localhost that are not certificated.

I have installed a self certification with the hope that using secure websockets and the certification it would work... Now I can access from localhost as https but I am unable to access from other devices without geting "This Connection is Untrusted"

There is any way to create a certified local network where I can browse to https://192.168.0.x (server IP) from other device and use websockets or secure websockets?

I am open to read other solutions where websockets work in a local network from an android browser.

Comment: Doesn't the browser require you to confirm a self-signed certificate? It should work after that.

Comment: When I browse "https://"serverIPfrom" my android I get the page "your connection is not private" and I have to click Advanced to continue to "http:// serverIP".
I don't get any page where I can confirm the self signed certificate.
Maybe I have made any error during the process of self-certification... 
I have created a self signed cert for "https://"test.site and on the server hosts added 127.0.0.1 to test.site. when I browse from the server "https://"test.site" it works fine, obviusly I can't browse "https://"test.site" from other devices on the LAN so I try to browse "https://"serverIP"